# Integral bounds for $x\geq yz$

Tags: probability, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, bounds-of-integration

[image]

I am having trouble understanding the integral bounds.

From what side should my understanding go (first or second?):

first: as $z$ is between zero and one, $y$ is also between zero and one, thus $x$ is between $yz$ and one.

second:as $x$ is between $1$ and $yz$, $y$ is between 0 and one, and $z$ is between zero and one.

Does it even matter from which side I go ?

Comment: It is $$\int_{z=0}^1\left[\int_{y=0}^1\left[ \int_{x=yz}^1 dx\right] dy\right]dz$$

Comment: As support of $x, y, z$ is $[0,1]^3$ and we must have $x \gt yz$. Checking support of $y$ and $z$, we see $0 \lt yz \lt 1$ for all values $0 \lt y \lt 1$ and $0 \lt z \lt 1$. That gives a clear bound for $x$ as $yz \lt x \lt 1$.

Comment: As said the integration order matters. The order chosen by the solution give us the simplest and most intuitive representation. If we interchange the order of the integration, the representation of the integration limits will also change